# Is there a setting in React Compound Timer that allows Double Zeros

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

Using React Compound Timer for some reoccurring events for a non-profit. Looking to see if there is a setting for a prefixed zero when the time unit is single digit? I could always make additional divs with logic but I’d rather use a setting if there is one! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `formatValue` property of the `Timer` class, to format the way its displayed.

Here is an example illustrating the same:

```
<Text style={{color:'white'}}>
  <Timer formatValue={(value) => `${(value < 10 ? `0${value}` : value)} units `}>
    <Timer.Hours formatValue={(value) => `${(value < 1 ? `` : (value < 10 ? `0${value}` : `${value} : `))}`} />
    <Timer.Minutes formatValue={(value) => `${(value < 10 ? `0${value} : ` : `${value} : `)}`} />
    <Timer.Seconds formatValue={(value) => `${(value < 10 ? `0${value}` : value)}`} />
  </Timer>
</Text>
```